# Parametrize a column name in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to find out if it's possible to parametrize a column name.
I have an example

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'region':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
               'id_1':[456, 456,    342,    987,    424,    424],
               'id_2':[98,  87, 65, 65, 32, 43],
               'id_3':[12,  12, 34, 34, 56, 56],
               'count':[1,0,1,1,0,0]})

reg_id=df.groupby(['region', 'id_1'])['count'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

[image]

The idea is to introduce a line for parametrization of id_columns. Something like this:

** ***column**=id_1*

** *reg_id=df.groupby(['region', **column**])['count'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)*

Changing this parameter I will be able to group by a column I need without changing anything in the script. Now i have several scripts for each column 'id'.

Comment: `reg_id=df.groupby(['region', column])['count'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)` works for me with `column='id_1'`

Comment: So you want a way to do this for all `id_` stubs without a different groupby each time?  Can you share exactly what you want the desired output to look like?

Comment: @user3483203, i want to change a column name to run the script whenever i need to do it for different columns. Not necessarily "groupby´" but all the data manipulations that i want to perform for this column

Comment: @anky, I have tried like this but it returns an error. Does it give the same results as when refer a column name?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing, specifically, what error message you're getting, it's hard to say where you're going wrong, but based on the code you pasted in the area with stars, I'm assuming your problem is that you're not saving the column_id as a string (which it should be).

The bracket notation and most other functions in pandas will accept the column names as strings, so you can save the column names as strings, which must be inside either single or double quotes. E.g.:

```
column_id = "id_1"
```

And then you can reference them with the variable as such:

```
reg_id=df.groupby(['region', column_id])['count'].value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Changing to

```
column_id = "id_2"
```

and running the second code block again will change the output from including `id_1` in `reg_id` to including `id_2` in it (and will group by it instead, but based on the lack of rows with repeated ids in the example you posted, that doesn't actually affect the counting/dummy-coding at all).